# Which UK children’s sci-fi TV show shown in the 1990s had a base with a stone circle entrance?

Tags: story-identification

For years I have tried to remember the name of a children's programme that was on (possibly on CITV, but could have been CBBC) when I was a child in the UK in the 90s. It may have been a rerun of an earlier broadcast.

My memories are vague but I remember there being a small circle of large stones, akin to something like Stonehenge, that opened up and allowed the characters to enter. I believe there were adults and children who entered a sci-fi themed base through the stones.

I seem to recall my dad saying that the main character was played by someone who had been a pop star or singer when he was younger.

Comment: Possibly the remake of The Tomorrow People? The main character was a former Neighbours star, although not a singer.

Comment: I've just had a look at it on YouTube and read the synopsis on Wikipedia and it's definitely not that. Thanks for the suggestion though. Not sure I'll get an answer as I can't find anything when I've looked. Makes me wonder whether I've dreamt it all up or confused several different programmes!

Comment: Could it have been Children of the Stones? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Stones

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've looked into that too and watched some of it on YouTube. I don't think it's that either. The show I remember (if it ever existed) was more sci-fi and I distinctly remember the characters going into the stones. I think that there was a door on them that led into a secret underground base. I think the adult (possible singer) guided a group of children who formed a team that helped him.

Comment: Power Rangers had a circular base, but it was a proper building, with rather high-tech stuff inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might have been one of the "Uncle Jack" series - I remember the villains (led by Fenella Fielding) having a sci-fi-ish underground base full of computer equipment in that.

### A screenshot of the underground base from *Uncle Jack and the Dark Side of the Moon*

[image: Image of the underground base from Uncle Jack and the Dark Side of the Moon (series 2)]

I don't recall any stone circle, but the man who played Uncle Jack was "an English singer, actor, harmonica player, radio personality and television presenter."

The bit about him leading a group of children - Jack (a secret Mi5 agent) led the rest of his family in his investigations, so this may fit.

### A clip from *Uncle Jack and the Dark Side of the Moon*. Watch from 16:02 in:

[This fansite](https://web.archive.org/web/20091027052218/http://geocities.com/vkrippen/) has more information, but its Flash menu doesn't play well with the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine, so here are the links to the subsections:

- [Series 1 - ... *and Operation Green*](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025220702/http://www.geocities.com/vkrippen/series1.html)
- [Series 2 - ... *and the Loch Noch Monster*](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025220702/http://www.geocities.com/vkrippen/series2.html)
- [Series 3 - ... *and the Dark Side of the Moon*](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025220702/http://www.geocities.com/vkrippen/series3.html)
- [Series 4 - ... *and Cleopatra's Mummy*](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025220702/http://www.geocities.com/vkrippen/series4.html)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show the OP that this is the series they're looking for?

Comment: It may be difficult to find one (and I'm at work just now!) The opening and closing credits for one series (probably not the one with the standing stones - if there were any) can be viewed at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_sRixwzlxc

Comment: There's another short clip at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxX-FPhc7QI but there are almost no screenshots or Youtube uploads, and buying one of the tie-in novelisations may be the only way to confirm whether or not a stone circle was involved. I think there may only have been one standing stone, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into this when you answered yesterday and only found the same as you. I'm wondering now whether I have confused this programme with elements of Children of the Stones. I've asked my dad to see if he can remember the show, so I'll see what he says. The lead once being a member of Manfred Mann indicates that it probably could be, at least in part, this show.

Comment: Just heard back from my dad who said Uncle Jack without any prompting from me. I'm Pretty certain now that my 6 year old mind has mixed two things together unless they did go into the stones in the standing stones episode. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20091027052218/http://geocities.com/vkrippen/ might be the best source, with episode synopses, but you have to paste the links into Archive.org rather than follow them.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I can't find any episode summary links in the archived page you link to, just a cast list.

Comment: @astrid_redfern You have to click into the season through the menu at the top left (you may have to turn on Flash) and then plug it back into the Wayback Machine. I'll try to remember to edit that in tonight.

Comment: It WAS Uncle Jack - in fact, it was series 3, "Uncle Jack and the Dark Side of the Moon". Episode 3 shows a villain using a hidden entrance in a standing stone to enter the underground base, and shows several smaller stones near it which OP might have mistaken for a ring of standing stones.

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking of [Earthfasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthfasts_(TV_series)). It featured future Eastenders star Paul Nicholls

> Schoolboys Keith and David (Chris Downs & Paul Nicholls) hear drumming
>   under the hill on the moor near their homes, and set out to
>   investigate. The hillside unexpectedly opens and Nellie Jack John
>   (Bryan Dick), a drummer boy from the 18th century marches into the
>   20th. Bewildered and lost in a strange world, he decides to go back
>   home.
>
> David discovers that the candle the drummer boy left behind gives off
>   cold rather than heat and does not burn down. Other strange things are
>   happening - standing stones are moving on the moors, the ground is
>   shaking and all the pigs have disappeared.
>
> Obsessed by the candle, David heads underground and does not return.
>   Keith searches for his friend. There is a strange encounter with
>   ghostly warriors.

Comment: Can you provide some backup details?